# Change default theme in multisite registration

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have a functionality where user can register for their free site and they get a sub domain. When new sub-domain is registered, by default, Twenty-Sixteen theme is activated, I want to change that to my custom theme. So that, whenever new sub domain is registered, my custom theme will be active by default.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your wp-config.php file and add the following code anywhere before the line where WordPress includes the wp-settings.php file `define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'your-default-theme' );` 
Change your-default-theme to your selected theme